# Argument of type error in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2013. The error says "argument of type "WCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *".

```
while (!processId)
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Searching for game" << ProcessName << "..." << endl;
    cout << "Make sure your game is running" << endl;
    hProcSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (Process32First(hProcSnap, &pe32))
    {
        do
        {
            if (!strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, ProcessName))
            {
                processId = pe32.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hProcSnap, &pe32));
    }
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

The error is on the following line. On my ide it is on "pe32"

> ```
>           if (!strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, ProcessName))
> ```

Comment: use wcscmp http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The signature of `strcmp` is

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Whereas `pe32.szExeFile` is a `TCHAR[]`, which is either `wchar_t[]` or `char[]` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined.  In your case, it is defined, so you need to either:

1. change `ProcessName` to a wide character string and use `wcscmp` to compare them.
2. use `_tcscmp()`, and make sure `ProcessName` is wide or narrow based on `UNICODE`.
3. use the ANSI versions of the APIs, which have a capital `A` appended to their names (e.g., `Process32FirstA()` and `Process32NextA()`).